P2200 Quadro on Dell PowerEdge T420
I need a support for GPU installation. I have an old T420 and P2200 Quadro GPU. The GPU has 75W max. power consumption and does not require any power connectors. If the setup failured, could I suspect on the health of x16 port or the GPU? The GPU is running now on another PC well. Dell documentation says Q4000 or Q6000 series are tested on T420 and the port maximum power support is 75W. What are your thoughts on this combination?

This should be plug and play if the motherboard has a pci-e x16 connector and the PSU has the room left for the extra 75W. Pci-e has standard specs which includes max 75W power delivery. It doesn't matter what extension card it is, GPU or anything else. For whatever reason this shouldn't work its most likely that the PSU doesn't have enough power or the pci-e slot on the motherboard is broken.

I have tried and it is working now. Thank you!
